# Android how do I check internet connection

Tags: java, android, sketchware

I want to be able to get a user internet connection. I have tried

```
boolean connected = false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        connected = nInfo != null && nInfo.isAvailable() && nInfo.isConnected();
        return connected;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Connectivity Exception", e.getMessage());
    }
    return connected;
```

But this only gets mobile data and wifi connection status, if the user has an expired data plan or doesn't even have any data plan I will not be able to know.
I want to know the internet status before making a server call instead of making a server and running in a runout time error.

Please help I have checked stack overflow, but I keep getting the same answer.

Comment: The only way your going to be able to do that is to ping a server. Until you actually try to send/receive data your not going to know the speed/stability of a connection

Comment: Thanks I lookup pinging I think it will be able to slove my problem.

Comment: kindly Find This Solution,  its about pinging, https://medium.com/dsc-alexandria/implementing-internet-connectivity-checker-in-android-apps-bf28230c4e86

Answer (score 1):

check internet coonnection with this function:

```
Boolean hasInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
        NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);

        if (capabilities != null) {
            if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) return true;
            else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) return true;
            else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)) return true;
            else return false;
        }

    } else {
        try {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this method returns `true` when you are connected to some network (e.g. wifi or ethernet), still this network may be some intranet. besides that this is Kotlin, not Java, which op want to use (due to tag)

Comment: @snachmsm i'm pretty sure it is a java code snippet. ;)

Comment: @programmerdreamer I'm pretty sure that there was some other comment above mine ;)